# How to dynamically change container size with text quantity in flutter?

Tags: flutter, containers, size

I want to create a container in flutter which changes its height according to the amount of text present in it.

If there is more text, it should cover more height, if text is less, it should cover less height.

Comment: Yes inside a column

Answer (score 2):

You can use fitted Box and width of container will help you to increase height dramatically.

```
FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: Container(width: 70,
          child:
      Text('hello '), color: Colors.red,
      )
         )
```